# How to increment key values by power of two

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I'm interested in storing multiple values in a single column, rather than use the traditional many-to-many table:

```
class Beer
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :containers, Integer # use bit arithmetic to store multiple values

  validates_presence_of :name, :containers

end

class Container
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial # increment in powers of two?
  property :name, String
  property :volume, Integer

  validates_presence_of :name, :volume

end
```

Containers:

```
ID  Name    Volume  Unit
1   Growler 64      oz
2   Cowler  32      oz
4   Bomber  750     mL
8   Six-fifty  650  mL
16  4 pack  64      oz
32  6 pack  72      oz
```

Beers:

```
ID  Name Containers
1   LSD  72
2   Düo  16
```

Is there an easy way to configure a DataMapper resource to increment serial values in powers of 2?  I'm assuming that the association is going to be a challenge.

Comment: what benefit could this have?

Comment: One fewer table to maintain.  Bitwise queries are fast and powerful.  That said, I'll probably need a helper function in the view to convert `Containers` to its string representation.

Comment: Everything about this is setting up for failure. Don't do this. Use sequential numbers and a proper relational table. You're going against the grain here in the worst possible way and it will be a constant struggle to keep things on track. Remember, Postgres has an `ARRAY` column and MySQL and Postgres both support `JSON` if you need an arbitrary data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `Serial` property type, but you can use an Integer and a `before :create` hook:

```
class Container
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Integer, key: true # Use whatever options you like
  property :name, String
  property :volume, Integer

  validates_presence_of :name, :volume

  # Create a new id based on the last element
  before :create do |c|
    last_container = Container.last
    # If integer has N bits, then you can only store N containers in your database (normally, 32 or 64 bits).
    c.id = last_container ? (last_container.id * 2) : 1
  end
end
```

Anyways, you should be using the relational model, instead of using this *hacky-tricks*, as someone already commented on your post. It's much more maintainable, easy to read and simple than this kind of solutions.

---

Oh, by the way, if you need fast access to your database, you should check a look at [Graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) and [neo4jrb](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j), an OGM for [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/).

Comment: Pretty slick solution.  I'll probably go the 'standard' route, as everyone is suggesting.